# SharePoint Online Show/Hide column based on permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, column

I have a couple of fields in a list that can only be modified by certain group of people. What is the best way to do this without a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have column level permissions, including 3rd party tools. Options:

- Customize the form with PowerApps, and hide/show fields based on permissions. Note, this is not security, this is just hiding fields. A savvy user could use other means of modifying the list. Also note, PowerApps is known to be buggy, so think twice before going down this road.
- Add a remote event handler. The event handler could check to see if the update is appropriate, and cancel out if not.
- Add a Flow. The flow could check to see if the update was appropriate, and if not it could send out email alerts, or otherwise flag the row. Note, this does not prevent updates, but could at least alert people that there was an inappropriate update.
- JavaScript or SPFx. There are other ways of customizing the UI for a form. They all suffer the same drawback which is that users with permissions can still do an update by simply bypassing the script/customization/etc.

Otherwise, create two lists. One list would be left open, and the other would be locked down to the specified group. A lookup could be used to tie the lists together, and perhaps custom powerapp, SPFx Part, etc., could bring the two lists together for viewing.